# Merge 2 text files based on first column using php

Tags: php, shell, file, concatenation

I have 2 log files with multiple lines like

first:

```
1|2016-04-13|...
3|2016-03-13|...
```

second:

```
2|POST|accept: txt|...
3|POST|accept: txt|...
```

Expected result:

```
3|2016-03-13|...|POST|accept: txt|...
```

So I need to combine all data in a single file based on first column (ID) using PHP scripting.

**Note**: count of rows can be different. Only intersection needed (order sensitive)

Comment: Does it have to be in PHP? If you are on a linux system, the "join" command will do exactly what you want; join -t '|' file1.txt file2.txt

Comment: I need php script and order of results shouldn't be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
<?php 
    exec ("awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}{if(a[$1]){print $2,a[$1]}}' first.log second.log > result.log");
?>
```

I used [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) php function to execute shell script

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}{if(a[$1]){print $2,a[$1]}}' first.log second.log > result.log
```

Here `-F'|'` specifies '|' symbol as delimiter, `first.log` and  `second.log` is my files to merge.

Answer (score 1):

open both log files.

you can use fopen and fgets (in foreach/while cycle) to get lines into array

or with file_get_contents explode the file by \n (\r\n on Win)

now you should have two arrays containing lines of both log files.
then you do this:

```
 $log1Lines = array("3|...|...", "4|...|...");
 $log2Lines = array("2|...|...", "3|...|...");

 $merged = array();

foreach($log1Lines as $row1){
     $id1 = explode("|", $row1)[0];
     foreach($log2Lines as $row2){
          $exploded = explode("|", $row2);
          $id2 = array_shift($exploded);
          if($id1 == $id2){
                $merged[$id1] = $row1 . "|" . implode("|", $exploded);
          }
     }
 }
 print_r($merged);
```

teoreticaly it should be doable without cycles (comparing parsed indexes between two arrays by array_intersect), but i have no solution doing it that way right now.

hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to write something fairly similar recently, so I've updated it a bit for your format. This will support more than 2 files if necessary, and allows changing the separator.

```
<?php
class Merger
{
    protected $separator = '|';
    protected $data = [];
    protected $initialised = false;

    public function mergeFile($filename)
    {
        $file = new SplFileObject($filename);
        $fileKeys = [];

        // Read the information out of the current file
        while (!$file->eof()) {
            $line = $file->fgets();
            $parts = explode($this->separator, trim($line));
            $id = array_shift($parts);
            $fileKeys[] = $id;

            $fileData[$id] = $parts;
        }

        // First pass: add everything
        if (!$this->initialised)
        {
            $this->data = $fileData;
        }

        // Subsequent passes, only add things that have already been seen, then
        // clear out anything that wasn't in the current file
        else
        {
            foreach ($fileData as $id => $data)
            {
                if ($this->data[$id])
                {
                    $this->data[$id] = array_merge($this->data[$id], $data);
                }
            }

            $this->data = array_filter($this->data, function ($e) use ($fileKeys) {
                return in_array($e, $fileKeys);
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
        }

        $this->initialised = true;
    }

    public function output($filename)
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $id => $data)
        {
            $output .= $id . $this->separator . implode($this->separator, $data) . PHP_EOL;
        }

        file_put_contents($filename, $output);
    }
}

$merger = new Merger;
$merger->mergeFile('1.txt');
$merger->mergeFile('2.txt');

echo $merger->output('output.txt');
```